# substring via sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have 2 kind of messages:

- `Board2Port1TS239.124.3.20:3000`
- `Board4UserTagZDF_pippo_MFPService8011`

If I receive the message 1 (it contains `Port`) the output should be `Board2Port1`

If I receive the message 2 (it doesn't contain `Port`) the output should be `Board4`

The numbers of `Board` and `Port` are not fixed.

```
/bin/echo "Board2Port1TS239.124.3.20:3000" | /bin/sed -e '/Port/ s/???/???/ ; /Port/! s/???/???/'
```

I can't find a solution... could anyone help me? thanks

---

Many thanks to Novocaine for the perfect solution.

I have another questione directly related to the previous one:

via shell the solution is ok:

```
[root@test3 snmptt]# /bin/echo 'Board2Port1TS239.124.3.21:3000' | /bin/sed -r 's/^(Board.(Port.)*).*/\1/g'
Board2Port1
```

Now I have to use this command inside a SNMPTT configuration. It doesn't work.
This is the snmptt.debug report

```
Done performing substitution on PREEXEC line: /bin/echo 'Board2Port1TS239.124.3.21:3000' | /bin/sed -r 's/^(Board.(Port.)*).*/\1/g'
PREEXEC command: /bin/echo 'Board2Port1TS239.124.3.21:3000' | /bin/sed -r 's/^(Board.(Port.)*).*/\1/g'
    command output: Board2Port1TS239.124.3.21:3000
```

The config file command is:

```
PREEXEC /bin/echo '$p2' | /bin/sed -r 's/^(Board.(Port.)*).*/\1/g'
```

the output "Board2Port1TS239.124.3.21:3000" is equal to the input ($p2). I don't undertstans why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/^(Board.(Port.)*).*/\1/g' File
```

Comment: It does work perfectly. Many thanks to you and to all the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you receive single message each time:

```
sed '/:/{s/\([0-9]\)[^0-9].*:/\1/;q};s/\([0-9]\)[^0-9].*/\1/'
```

should work:

```
kent$  sed '/:/{s/\([0-9]\)[^0-9].*:/\1/;q};s/\([0-9]\)[^0-9].*/\1/' <<< "Board2Port1TS239.124.3.20:3000"                                                                   
Board23000

kent$  sed '/:/{s/\([0-9]\)[^0-9].*:/\1/;q};s/\([0-9]\)[^0-9].*/\1/' <<< "Board4whatever3000"             
Board4
```

Comment: Hi, it is not correct:
the messages contain always the word Board, sometimes contain Port OR UserTag.
I have to perform the check with Port.
If Port is present, the output should be BoardxPorty
If Port is not present the outpunt should be Board4

Comment: @MarcoMurtas You didn't mention there are fixed text (Board/Port) in your intput file. Fixed stuff usually makes problem easier. At least this answer showed you the idea how I was thinking to solve this problem. The input could vary from time to time, however the idea comes to solution is the key point. my 2cents.

Comment: @MarcoMurtas well perhaps I misunderstood your `contains Port`.. I thought it contains the port number (or not).

Comment: only the word Board is always contained in the message. Sometimes the word Port is present, sometimes no. Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input really looks like your example, and that `Port` and `UserTag` are fixed strings:

```
sed -r '/Port/{s/TS.*//;n};s/UserTag.*//'
```

Comment: Hi, it is not correct:
the messages contain always the word Board, sometimes contain Port OR UserTag.
I have to perform the check with Port.
If Port is present, the output should be BoardxPorty
If Port is not present the outpunt should be Board4